# Removing trackpad drag delay

Tags: macos

I've just switched from Windows and the only thing I miss is that there was no delay when dragging something on Windows. For example, if I'm dragging a tab on the browser to reposition it, I can't just let go immediately once I have it in the new position I want like I can on Windows. I either have to tap/click or wait a whole second, which is jarring.

This doesn't just apply to dragging. I was just tutoring a student on Zoom today with the Mac for the first time and it was very inconvenient when I was drawing on the Whiteboard and had to wait a whole second after drawing a single line to draw another one.

I've tried the three finger drag, and though there's no delay with that I just don't find it comfortable. Surely there's something I can do about this? I've tried BetterTouchTool but it no longer allows one to do this. Thank you.